# Ubuntu installation: GRUB fails to install

Tags: ubuntu, installation, grub

Many times I've tried installing Ubuntu in an computer, however it always fails to install GRUB. 
It always displays an fatal error message.
I boot the Ubuntu network installer via an pendrive with YUMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely YUMI is trying to install GRUB on your pendrive, instead of your hard disk.

1. In the beginning of the installation, when selecting the partition on which to install Ubuntu, check which one is your hard disk.
2. Since you experienced this error, your hard disk is probably sdb or sdc.
3. When you see the prompt asking if you want to install GRUB to MBR, select no.
4. In the next prompt, asking what partition or drive should GRUB be installed on, type in the same partition (or drive) that you selected to install Ubuntu on.